# Jquery animation stops on load callback

Tags: jquery, animation, load

I want to do something a little tricky:

i have 2 non nested div, let's call it "text" and "content". I want to:
on user click:

1. fade out the actual text in "text"
2. fade in a loading text and start loading a page with .load

on the end of the .load instruction:

1. fade out the loading text
2. change html of the content div to the loaded page
3. slideDown my just loaded content div

here my code:

```
$("#text").click(function () {
            console.log("click!");
            $('#content').fadeOut(400, function () {
                console.log("first Fade out complete!");
                $('#content').text('Loading..').fadeIn(400, function () {
                    console.log("first Fade in complete!");
                    $('#text').load('imageMenu.aspx', function () {
                        console.log("Load complete!");
                        $('#content').fadeOut(400, function () {
                            console.log("Second fadeout complete!");
                            $('#text').slideDown();
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
```

but it doesn't work, in my console i have:

> click!
>
> first Fade out complete!
>
> first Fade in complete!
>
> Load complete!

and i get the content loaded without any animation after the load completition! what i'm doing wrong?
looks like the load callback is not called nor executed!

Comment: Is it working as you describe in all browsers?

Comment: yes, i just tried with chrome, firefox, opera, ie10, same result.
but something odd is happening here, now it doesn't work even with the load and slidedown commands alone.. :\

Comment: I am wondering if performing the load on the same element that you are tying the click event to is effecting the event from continuing.  Try creating a third element to load the image into just to test that theory.

Comment: yeah Felda thats something like that! I got it working with a third element! Seems like the slideDown works only with totally hidden elements, my "text" element was already visible and it cannot work! Thanks now is perfect :D

Comment: Oh, totally missed that.  So if you add $('#text').hide() right before you slide down, it works?

Comment: i haven't tried but i suppose it works with an initial .hide()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you add your HTML code to test it?

Why don´t you use the $.ajax() method

somethig like:

```
        $('#content').fadeOut(400, function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'imageMenu.aspx',
                success: function(result) {
                    console.log("Load complete!");
                    $('#content').fadeOut(400, function() {
                        console.log("Second fadeout complete!");
                        $('#text').slideDown();
                    });

                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: yeah thats will work, in my case the real problem was in trying to slideDown an already visible element! Thank you for your help too!